# Matplotlib: setting the figsize very big cause the xtick and yticks hidden

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a double barplot. I found that When I set `figsize=(20,10)`, the xtick and ytick are visible and normal(that is what I want) as the first plot in below, however, when only change the figsize to `figsize=(200,100)`, xtick and ytick are disappeared as the second plot in below. Can anybody tell me why that happen and how to solve it?

```
From matplotlib.pyplot import *     
figure(figsize=(20,10))
X = range(10)
Y1 = array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
Y2 = array([23.9218945 , 25.70771409, 33.56520973, 16.01795171, 11.52174436,
               14.53292673, 27.88619997,  1.4717423 ,  2.78468413, 13.70871468])
        
    
bar(X, +Y1, facecolor='#9999ff', edgecolor='white')
bar(X, -Y2, facecolor='#ff9999', edgecolor='white')
tight_layout()
show()
```

[image]

```
From matplotlib.pyplot import *      
figure(figsize=(200,100))
X = range(10)
Y1 = array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
Y2 = array([23.9218945 , 25.70771409, 33.56520973, 16.01795171, 11.52174436,
       14.53292673, 27.88619997,  1.4717423 ,  2.78468413, 13.70871468])


bar(X, +Y1, facecolor='#9999ff', edgecolor='white')
bar(X, -Y2, facecolor='#ff9999', edgecolor='white')
tight_layout()
show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the reason and solution.
The reason is that if the `figsize` is set to large. The `xticks` and `yticks` will be too small to be visible. So it is not actually disappear, it is because the fonts are just too small.

The solution is modify the `fontsize` of `xticks` and `yticks`

```
From matplotlib.pyplot import *      
figure(figsize=(200,100))
X = range(10)
Y1 = array([100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
Y2 = array([23.9218945 , 25.70771409, 33.56520973, 16.01795171, 11.52174436,
       14.53292673, 27.88619997,  1.4717423 ,  2.78468413, 13.70871468])


bar(X, +Y1, facecolor='#9999ff', edgecolor='white')
bar(X, -Y2, facecolor='#ff9999', edgecolor='white')
 


xticks(fontsize =40)
yticks( fontsize =40)

show()
```

Comment: You have a poster that's literally 5.0m × 2.5m , when you look at  it from a comfortable distance, as a distance from which the whole of it fits in the centre of your field of view, how can you imagine to read something written on it in the size this comment is typeset?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of Matplotlib, it's rather a problem of visual acuity.

Your figure is literally 5×2.5 metres large, when you place this billboard at a comfortable seeing distance, so that it fits in the centre of your visual field, it's very unlikely that you can discern the letters of the labels, that have approximately the physical dimensions of the letters you are now reading on the screen.

I have saved your figure in PDF format and later I have opened the PDF in a viewer, first at an unknown zoom level for which the whole page fits on screen an later at 100% zoom level (so that, dpi issues notwithstanding, we see essentially a **small detail** of the figure — remember, the figure is about 5.0m by 2.5m, the computer screen is about 0.3m by 0.2m — at real scale).

Here I post the two screenshots, take into account that SO further resizes the images so in the full page view you'll see nothing except the bars, while when you open the image in a new tab and go 100% you will realize that there are a number of fly poops in the borders of the image…

[image: zoom to fit page on screen]

[image]

---

#### Side remark

Someone could possibly wonder *"What is that prehistoric kind of interface you used?"*.

Well, previously I tried with `evince`, that chose a zoom level and did not let me change it! and tried also `mupdf`, that opened the file and utterly blocked `X` until I switched to a virtual console to kill it.

On the other hand, the prehistoric `xpdf` opened the file w/o a glitch and let me change the zoom level to my content.  Kudos to `xpdf`.